# opencv causes segfaults because it does not use system install of zlib

Tags: ros, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We cannot get anything working unless this is fixed. I reported it here:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/970

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9609/opencv-causes-segfaults-because-it-does-not-use-system-install-of-zlib/) by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 516 on 2011-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be great if someone fixes this, the patch is already provided.

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2011-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0